# typescript classes exports and imports not working properly inside a react app

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a problem with importing classes inside typescript react app.
I have no errors prior running the build.
For some reasons when I run the build i get the error of Property 'x' does not exist on type 'classx'.
This property is within a class, and I can access it from anywhere within that class (it is private), and it shows in intellisense with all metadata.
Prior to build i get NO errors!
Code example of this error:

```
export class MyClass {
  private _wrappedClass: WrappedClass
  constructor(wrappedClass:WrappedClass){
     this._wrappedClass = wrappedClass
  }
}
```

This code would throw error Property '_wrappedClass' does not exist on type 'MyClass'

Comment: This code by itself gives no errors, so we'll need a bit more context of how you use it. When does the error start to appear? Can you use `MyClass` at all in your project?

Comment: I can't use MyClass or any other typescript class... on any class I import into tsx file I get these errors on build... In the meantime I get no errors while writing the code. In intellisense I get all of the pbulic methods with metadata. Everything works while I'm just writing code

Comment: Maybe your own code doesn't get included when you run the `npm run build` command? Is your MyClass code in the right folder? Maybe the path you use in `import ... from MyClass` isn't correct when you build?

Comment: Typescript autoimports from project when you start typing and it would underline wrong import. Important note is that this was originally a javascript react app which was only recently switched to typescript.

Comment: I have managed to solve this problem partially. For some you can't import typescript classes into a tsx file and expect them to work unless they are also defined within a tsx file. Temporary solution is to import React and save a file as .tsx then it works as expected. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem partially. For some you can't import typescript classes into a tsx file and expect them to work unless they are also defined within a tsx file. Temporary solution is to import React and save a file as .tsx then it works as expected. Thank you for your effort.